# Get the IMG of the current 'slick' slide (vanilla JS or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, slick.js

This is the very famous "slick" I am talking about: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I found this PERFECTLY WORKING answer:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  slide: 'div',
  cssEase: 'linear'
 });

$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  //Here I do split the `src` attribute value because I'm using an absolute path.
  // $(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)) gives the whole slide 
  var CurrentImg=$(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)).find('img').attr('src').split('/').pop();
  console.log(CurrentImg)
});
```

My problem is that IF I NEVER TOUCH THE SLIDE, the event is NEVER CALLED and so I have no clue of the current image.

If I simply try in any onclick this:

```
$(slick.$slides.get(currentSlide)).find('img').attr('src').split('/').pop()
```

Of course it doesn't work, because "slick" is never defined.
If I do

```
slick = $('.slider').slick({
....
```

it's not correct either, telling me that slick.$slides is not defined.

Where can I get the correct reference to "slick" if I am NOT in an event?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple slick slider on one page, so to get one specifically you can use `.slick(getSlick)` for getting the current slick object:

`$('.selector .for .one .slick-slider').slick('getSlick')`

If you then check under `$slides` you see all slides, filter out the one with the class name `slick-slide-current` and you have your current slide for the selected slick slider. `.get(currentSlide)` didn't work at this part for me, but you should be able to filter out the element.

Check out the section ["Methods" on the official documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: Thanks it worked but since JS is not 'my language', I did this to find it. It works, but I am sure there is an easier way....   var currentSlide = -1;
  for(i=0; i<mySlides.length; ++i) {
    tmp = $(mySlides[i]).attr('class')
    if (tmp.indexOf('slick-current')) {
      currentSlide = i;
      break
    }
  }